# Can't query clickhouse db using nodejs

Tags: node.js, clickhouse

I'm getting an Error when querying to clickhouse db.."

```js
const { ClickHouse } = require('clickhouse');
const clickhouse = new ClickHouse({
  debug: false,
  basicAuth: {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password',
  },
});
clickhouse.query('SHOW DATABASES;').exec((err, rows) => {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(rows);
});
```

--> ==== Output =====

[nodemon] starting node index.js
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND http
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26) {
errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'http'
}
undefined

Comment: You forgot `url` and `port ` properties when create an instance of `ClickHouse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the host and the port on which clickhouse is hosted

```
const { ClickHouse } = require('clickhouse');
const clickhouse = new ClickHouse(url: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DATABASE_PORT),
    debug: false,
    basicAuth: {
        username: "username",
        password: "password"
    },
    isUseGzip: false,
    config: {
        session_timeout: 60,
        output_format_json_quote_64bit_integers: 0,
        enable_http_compression: 0
    });
clickhouse.query('SHOW DATABASES;').exec((err, rows) => {
console.log(err);
console.log(rows);
})
```